# Is there a bug when using code highlighting with URL's?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown, hyperlinks, highlighting

I just recognized that when I use grave accents (`) to highlight code and insert a URL into this, then the URL does somehow not getting resolved. Using `<code>` works.

The output is something like this: `[String.Format][1]`.

What I actually wanted to write: `String.Format`

Comment: Not a bug, that's by design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this works *exactly* as intended.

*Everything* inside the grave accents will be displayed as code, no matter if it could be interpreted as wiki syntax.

If you want a code block as link, put the accents inside the square braces: [`String.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
[`String.Format`][1]
```

Comment: Thanks for undeceiving me :-)